# Bug ubuntu 22.10: "finished - wait until snapd is fully seeded"

Tags: 22.10

Pesquisando, parece ser um bug recorrente de versões anteriores que ainda não foi corrigido.

Trata-se de uma instalação nova do ubuntu, de ontem, 20/10/2022;

a) instalamos alguns programas, gimp, vlc, brave, chrome, fuse, kdenlive
b) desligamos o computador.
d) após o boot novo, travou na mensagem de erro:

"finished - wait until snapd is fully seeded"
e) alternando a tela travada (alt+f2) removi o programa snap (apt remove snap)

f) depois disso travou na tela do kernel :
dev loop1 unable to read rdb block 8

g) solução: reinstalei o ubuntu e estou procurando se este bug terrível vai reaparecer, com medo de perder novamente a instalação atual.

problema este inadimissível ...

Specs:
Ubuntu 22.10
PC: ryzen 7 3700x; 32gb memória; nvme 256gb; amd rx 580 8gb;

http://dsamaz.byethost18.com/tmp/20221021_113238.jpg
http://dsamaz.byethost18.com/tmp/20221021_112648.jpg

---

This is a fresh install of ubuntu, from yesterday, 10/20/2022;

a) we install some programs, gimp, vlc, brave, chrome, fuse, kdenlive b) we turn off the computer. d) after new boot, stuck on error message:

"finished - wait until snapd is fully seeded" e) toggling locked screen (alt+f2) removed snap program (apt remove snap)

f) after that stuck on kernel screen : dev loop1 unable to read rdb block 8

g) solution: I reinstalled ubuntu and I'm looking if this terrible bug will reappear, for fear of losing the current installation again.

problem is unacceptable...

Specs: Ubuntu 22.10 PC: ryzen 7 3700x; 32gb memory; nvme 256gb; amd rx 580 8gb;

Comment: v22.10 is an interim version. You might find more stability with the current LTS version 22.04

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English-only site, please only write in English.

Answer (score 0):

Depuramos aqui o bug, apareceu outra vez:
a) instalar o ubuntu 22.10 desktop
b) instalar o programa fuse: apt install fuse (por padrão ele remove ubuntu-desktop)
c) o PC não inicia mais normalmente (x11, gráfico)

Solução temporária: abrir outro terminal (ctrl+alt+f2) e instalar ubuntu-desktop (sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop), depois reboot

English:
Here we debug the bug, it appeared again:
a) install ubuntu 22.10 desktop
b) install the fuse program: apt install fuse (by default it removes ubuntu-desktop)
c) PC no longer starts normally (x11, graphic)

Temporary solution: open another terminal (ctrl+alt+f2) and install ubuntu-desktop  (sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop), then reboot